# Query two table and concat the table value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Refer to below table `article` and `article_image`

TABLE article

```
id a_id title
1  1    abc
2  2    def
3  3    ghi
4  4    jkl
5  5    mno
```

TABLE article_image

```
id a_id image
1  1    a.jpg
2  1    b.jpg
3  1    c.jpg
4  3    d.jpg
5  3    e.jpg
6  3    f.jpg
7  4    g.jpg
8  4    h.jpg
```

I tried the query

`SELECT article.a_id, article.title, article_image.image
FROM article
JOIN article_image
ON (article.a_id = article_image.a_id)
GROUP BY article_image.thumbnail`

But the result is not what I wanted, the **expected result** should be:

```
a_id tilte image
1    abc   a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg
2    def
3    ghi   d.jpg, e.jpg, f.jpg
4    jkl   g.jpg, h.jpg
5    mno
```

Could someone advise how to query these two table to result as above?

Thanks

Comment: remove the group by clause and use Left join instead of join then see what is the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the MySQL built-in function [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), with `LEFT JOIN` to include those articles that had no images in the other table:

```
SELECT 
  article.a_id, 
  article.title, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(article_image.image  SEPARATOR ',') AS images
FROM article 
LEFT JOIN article_image ON article.a_id = article_image.a_id
GROUP BY article.a_id, 
         article.title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT article.a_id, article.title, article_image.image FROM article
INNER JOIN article_iamge ON article.a_id = article_image.a_id
```